# How to know in apache logs if the application has crashed?

Tags: apache, logging, apache-log-files

I need some help in finding some log pattern in apache logs related to application cash? Is there a specific key word attached related to this event e.g 'crash'.

Thanks.

Comment: This would need a lot more information in the question to be helpful I'm afraid. What is the application? What language/system? What type of crash? etc

Comment: @joesk thank you for the answer. The application is purely web-application mostly with db connectivity, written in php or asp.net

Comment: @user970533 - You could look in the `error.log` file(s) for 'Apache service started' or similar, when you KNOW Apache was already running. Usually, a crash is silent in the sense that Apache restarts immediately and it can be hard to detect. Specifically if an APPLICATION crashes, you'll need to specify the exact problem: if you mean the App has some sort of malfunction itself, or if Apache is to blame. We cannot answer specifically without this.

Comment: @ionFish i respect this, so its all dependent upon application nature, different application produces different sounds (error). The best way it can be done if application itself make custom logs messages i suppose

Comment: Yes, if your APP crashes but NOT Apache, then you'll have to perhaps look for PHP logs or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look in the error.log file(s) for 'Apache service started' or similar, when you KNOW Apache was already running. Usually, a crash is silent in the sense that Apache restarts immediately and it can be hard to detect. Specifically if an APPLICATION crashes, but NOT Apache, then you'll have to perhaps look for PHP logs or something.